# How to group dataframe NaN values of one feature by another feature

Tags: python, pandas

**Situation**: I have a DataFrame with NaN values.
I'm going to make a prognosis of sth for the next year, so I guess i don't need very old data.
I want to check the 'structure' of NaNs to see if there are lots of them in old data, and not so much in the new ones.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['year','water_consumption','some_index'], 
                  data = [[1, float('nan'),3],[2,26,7], [5,float('nan'),6], 
                         [1,float('nan'),42],[1,float('nan'),13]])
```

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | NaN | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 26.0 | 7 |
| 2 | 5 | NaN | 6 |
| 3 | 1 | NaN | 42 |
| 4 | 1 | NaN | 13 |

The question is: how can I group number of NaN values in feature_one by values of feature_two easily (I know I can make a list and cycling by every value of feature_one and then count them, but I'd like to know if there is any easier and more elegant way)? Groupby has no 'isna()' method.

In the end i want to see a table like:

|  | A | B_nan_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

First compare `B` for boolean mask and for count aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = df.B.isna().groupby(df.A).sum().reset_index(name='B_nan_count')
```

Your solution filter rows, so `df[df.B.isna()]` return DataFrame, so for count use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
df1 = df[df.B.isna()].groupby('A').size().reset_index(name='B_nan_count')
```